# Where can I find previous alerts or warnings?

Tags: ios, notifications

Where can I find previous iPad alerts or warnings?

Answer (score 2):

Many alerts are shown in Notification Center, available by pulling down from the top of the display.

You can configure which notifications are stored in Notification Center in Settings → Notifications.

For more information about notifications, see

- [Use Notifications on your iPhone, iPad, and iPod touch](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT201925)

Comment: you don't see these every day :-) https://i.stack.imgur.com/dRaXo.jpg